# How to pass a variable in fileupload accept tool in asp

Tags: asp.net

How to pass a variable in file Upload accept tool ?

FrmFileUpload.aspx.cs

```
String Ext=".pdf";

FrmFileUpload.aspx

<asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload1" runat="server"  accept='<%=Ext%>' class="filestyle" data-icon="false" data-classbutton="btn btn-default" Width="500px" data-classinput="form-control inline input-s" AllowMultiple="true"/>
```

FrmFileUpload.aspx.cs

```
String Ext=".pdf";

FrmFileUpload.aspx


<asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload1" runat="server"  accept="Ext" class="filestyle" data-icon="false" data-classbutton="btn btn-default" Width="500px" data-classinput="form-control inline input-s" AllowMultiple="true"/>
```

pass variable in accept fileupload tool.

Comment: `FileUpload1.Attributes.Add("accept", ".gif,.jpg,.png");`

Comment: problem solved.Thanks for your reply.